# Multiple Objective Optimization Java

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I've implemented a linear programming problem using the CPLEX API in Java. This problem has 5 linear objectives with different scales. I've tried to implement some normalization methods, but without success. Despite getting a result between 0 and 1, they end up with different orders of magnitude (as I'm using a weighted sum, this is a problem).

Now, I'm wondering to implement this problem with multi-objective optimization using, perhaps, priority criterion. Does CPLEX allow one to implement it? I didn't find much information nor examples. And if not, what are the possible workarounds?

Comment: Can you give example of how a result between 0-1 ends up with differing orders of magnitude?  Confused by your question.  Also, prioritization amongst variables in the objective function is usually handled by weighting them appropriately.  What would a priority criterion do?

Comment: @JeffH, for instance, one objective has cost 10E-1 and the other has 10E-5. Multi objective with prioritization will overcome this issues by telling the importance of each objective, instead of using a weighted sum.

Comment: how about using jMetal instead for multi criteria optimization?

Comment: You can use a weighted sum approach after normalization. With lexicographic approach trade-offs are basically ignored (which may or may not be what you want).

Answer (score 2):

With CPLEX 12.9 you may use multi objective.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes1290/newJavaAPI.html

> In the Java API of CPLEX V12.9.0, the new implementation of multiobjective optimization offers these new classes and methods. They are documented in the reference manual of the Java API of CPLEX.
>
> These new methods support multiobjective optimization:
>
> ```
> IloCplex.staticLex()
> ```

Comment: How can I use it? Did you found any example?

Comment: For documentation about multi-objective see the user manual at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/multiobj/partMultiobj_title_synopsis.html. In particular the section about examples. The examples with multi-objective in Java are `MultiObjEx1.java` and `Diet.java`.